# How to make a batch file to execute win rar in multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, winrar

Iam really new to batch files so pls bear with me.
I want to make a batch file that can take folders from different locations and then zip it in to one win rar file in a location like

```
c:\projects\test 
c:\www\site
c:\logs\office
```

to

```
c:backup\{{date}}_backup.rar
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
(
echo c:\projects\test 
echo c:\www\site
echo c:\logs\office
)>list.txt
"%programfiles%\winrar\rar" a "c:\backup\%date:/=-%_backup.rar" @list.txt
```

If you are on Win-x64 set the rar path: `"%programfiles(x86)%\winrar\rar"`